# ajax object from view to controller not containing data

Tags: c#, jquery, .net, ajax, asp.net-core-mvc

> >
>   I .net core 2.2 This is the object Object:

```
[Serializable]
public class oob
{
   public int i { get; set; }
   public string j { get; set; }
}
```

this is the action in "Home" Controller named Gett that takes oob as input from ajax

```
 [HttpGet]
public IActionResult Gett(oob ww)
{
    return Ok(ww);
}
```

Ajax

```
    {
        $.ajax({
            type: "Get",
            url: "Home/gett",
            data: { ww: JSON.stringify({i:55,j:"weqe"})},
            dataType: "json",
            contentType:"json",
            success: function (f) {
                console.log(f);
            },
            error: function (f) {
                console.log(f);
            }
        });
    });
```

When request is made ,at the Gett(oob ww) i  get an object with value of i=0 and j=null

Comment: You mean: return Ok(ww) instead of OK(i). right ?

Comment: Sorry  yes @ Abdullah Dibas

Comment: Try ContentType 'application/json'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ideally you should not pass  object to a `GET` request, for posting object, you should use `POST`.

If you still want, you need to change your GET method like following using `FromQuery`.

```
[HttpGet]
public IActionResult Gett([FromQuery] oob ww)
{
    return Ok(ww);
}
```

And change your `AJAX` call like following.

```
$.ajax({
            type: "Get",
            url: "Home/gett",
            data: {i:55,j:"weqe"},
            dataType: "json",
            contentType:"json",
            success: function (f) {
                console.log(f);
            },
            error: function (f) {
                console.log(f);
            }
        });
```

**Note:** To pass the object you don't need `JSON.stringify` if you are using `FromQuery` for your `API`

Comment: can you change data:{ ww: JSON.stringify({i:55,j:"weqe"})} to  data:JSON.stringify({i:55,j:"weqe"})

Comment: .net core 2.2     MVC controller

Comment: just change  data: {i:55,j:"weqe"}, I tested locally and its working

Comment: and use [FromQuery]